# Jquery.param() not serializing object correctly

Tags: jquery, serialization

i'm having trouble with jQuery.param() adding an empty array key when serializing an object

```
payload: {
    "page":0,
    "size":30,
    "query":"",
    "facets": {
        "category": [
            "tagName1",
            "tagName2"
        ]
    }
}
```

What i get when i serialize payload is:

```
page=0&size=30&query=&facets%5Bcategory%5D%5B%5D=tagName1&facets%5Bcategory%5D%5B%5D=tagName2
```

url decoded:

```
page=0&size=30&query=&facets[category][]=tagName1&facets[category][]=tagName2
```

what i'm expecting is (url decoded):

```
page=0&size=30&query=&facets[category]=tagName1&facets[category]=tagName2
```

Are my expectations wrong, is this a bug in jquery serialization or is it intended behaviour?

Thanks in advance

Comment: serialise how? Show code - for example in a snippet. serialize is for forms

Comment: The brackets `[]` after arrays are added to make languages like PHP happy IIRC. Passing `true` in the second argument to `$.param()` should fix that problem.

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi unfortunately if i pass true in the second argument it won't enter the object at all and just print `...&facets=[object object]...`

Comment: This is actually the result specified in http://api.jquery.com/jquery.param/ - as @FrédéricHamidi wrote, you can pass `true` as the second argument to the function for a  "shallow" serialization - but then it will not work correctly with nested objects (also described on the API page).

Comment: @Karim, well, the documentation does say *Because some frameworks have limited ability to parse serialized arrays, developers should exercise caution when passing an obj argument that contains objects or arrays nested within another array.* It appears you have hit that case. You will probably have better luck by using plain JSON instead of `$.param()`.

Answer (score 1):

It appears that this is intended behaviour indeed.

I ended up doing a string replace inside the beforeSend hook